# i want to find coordinates of image

Tags: java, selenium, pointers, coordinates

I want to validate that the image should be display in right corner of page.

```
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
    Point point = element.getLocation();
    System.out.println("Element's Position from left side is: "+point.getX()+" pixels.");
    System.out.println("Element's Position from top is: "+point.getY()+" pixels.");
```

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code for getting coordinates of element

```
     IOSElement element = driver.findElementByName(xpath);
     int leftX = element.getLocation().getX();
     int rightX = leftX + element.getSize().getWidth();
     int middleX = (rightX + leftX) / 2;
     int upperY = element.getLocation().getY();
     int lowerY = upperY + element.getSize().getHeight();
     int middleY = (upperY + lowerY) / 2;
     //System.out.println("x co-ordinat: "+middleX+"\n y co-ordinat: "+middleY+"\n left x axis: "+leftX+"\n right x: "+rightX);
     System.out.println("x co-ordinat: "+upperY+"\n y co-ordinat: "+lowerY+"\n left x axis: "+leftX+"\n right x: "+rightX);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.getSize()` to get the `Dimension` object. `Use getWidth()` on the Dimension object. Add the width to the `point.getX()` to get the right edge.

Use the `driver.manage().window().getSize()` which also returns the a Dimension object. You can again get the width using `getWidth()` on Dimension object.

```
int elementRightEdge = element.getLocation().getX() + element.getSize().getWidth();
int windowRightEdge = driver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
```